# How IE Browse Mode Changed to 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

We have a web portal product and contains  multiple iframes, js files and css files. Every time I visit the portal using IE11, the browse mode becomes 8, as shown in F12.

The weird thing is, I checked ALL requests and responses in Network in F12 Developer Tools, and only three response headers contains x-ua-compatible. The values are

```
IE=Edge 
IE=EmulateIE7 
IE=EmulateIE7
```

I have no idea where IE8 comes from?

**Also in our DEV portal, the same product, it shows Browse Mode = Edge, even the same three values also present.** It seems the browser mode is changed somewhere else outside Network/F12. I guess it is not javascript. But what can change IE's document mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be related to Enterprise Mode? I think this is something that network administrators can set up.

If your product is accessible from the internet, I'd try using IE11 on a computer outside of work and see what happens.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/what-is-enterprise-mode

Comment: Thank you for saving my life!